# field date andtwo field should not be the same

Tags: odoo

I want ask following thing

1. I have two field, but field A and field B should not have the same contents
2. I just write some function, here my code :

   ```
   def _check_date(self,cr,uid,ids,context=None):
           sessions = self.browse(cr,uid,ids,context=context)
           check = True

           for session in sessions:
               check = check and (not session.depart_date < time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

           return check

   def check_date_validation(self,depart_date):

               check = True
               check = check and (not depart_date< time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

               return check

   _constraints = [(_check_date, 'Date cannot earlier than today',['depart_date'])]

   def check_constraints(self,cr,uid,id,depart_date,context=None):
           warning = {}

           if not self.check_date_validation(depart_date):
               title = _("Warning Title")
               message = _("Warning Message")
               warning = {
                       'title': title,
                       'message': message,
               }
               depart_date = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
           else:
               depart_date = depart_date
           return {'value': {'depart_date': depart_date},'warning':warning}
   ```

That function mean **date should not be smaller than the current date**
but..I want make again. field date A and B should not be the same. can you help me. Please....

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wht I understood is that you want depart_date should be more then current date and not equal to current date.

so try

```
check = check and (not session.depart_date <= time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

if I was not able to address it then please elaborate and also advice if the dept_date is less then what is the value of check in the above statement ?

Comment: the above code is correct ... now I want to know how to date.depart not be the same as date.return
departure city and ... field should not be the same as the field of arrival

Comment: just paste it on line 6 , 13 :)